# flutter DropdownButtonFormField long item not fully displayed

Tags: flutter, widget

when DropdownMenuItem is not fully displayed because of its height. so Im wonseringhow can I make the size change dynamically to fully display the chosen item

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
                      isExpanded: true,
                      validator: (value){
                        if(value== null){
                          return "Campo vuoto";
                        }
                        else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      decoration:InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Locale",
                          border:  OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
                          )
                      ) ,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          chosenService = value.toString();
                        });
                      },
                      items: locals.map((local) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(local.name,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color(Helper.getColorByType(local.type)), fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                            overflow: TextOverflow.visible),
                        Text(Helper.getAdressFromDescription(local.description), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.black54),
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
              value: local.type+' - '+local.name,
            ),
          ).toList(),
                    ),
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPR4j.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XGi8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it can help you

```
SizedBox(
height: 100//I use default value as well but you can another value or MediaQuery
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / x.x, //try ideal values
child: DropdownButtonFormField(
         ...
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none, contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),  ),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        ...
),
```